# Find the antiderivative of $f(x) = x^{-1}$ for $x \ge 1$ and $f(x) = x^{-2}$ for $0<x<1$

Tags: calculus, integration

$\mathbf{EDIT}$: the original definition of the problem had an error. $F(e)$ has to be equal $\frac{5}{3}$ not $1$.

I need to find the antiderivative $F$ of

$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x^{-1} \qquad x \ge 1 \\
x^{-2} \qquad 0<x<1
\end{cases}
$

such that $F(e) = 1$.

$\mathbf{First:}$

$F(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\ln|x| + c_1 \qquad x \ge 1 \\
-\frac{1}{x} + c_2 \qquad 0<x<1
\end{cases}
$

$\mathbf{Secondly}$, we need to make sure that $F(x)$ is continuous at $x=1$:

$$\lim_{x \to 1^+} F(x) = \lim_{x \to 1^-} F(x)$$
Which is:
$$\ln1+c_1 = c_2-1 \Rightarrow c_1 = c_2 - 1$$
Therefore:

$F(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\ln|x| + c_2 - 1 \qquad x \ge 1 \\
-\frac{1}{x} + c_2 \qquad 0<x<1
\end{cases}
$

$\mathbf{Lastly}$, we need to make sure that $F(e) = 1$:

$$\ln e+ c_2 - 1 = 1$$
$$1+ c_2 - 1 = 1$$
$$c_2 = 1$$

$\mathbf{Finally}$, this is the antiderivative:

$F(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\ln|x| \qquad x \ge 1 \\
-\frac{1}{x} + 1 \qquad 0<x<1
\end{cases}
$

I think something is wrong in my calculations because I need to calculate

$F(e^2)+F(e^{-1})+F(e)+F'(0.5)+F'(2)$ where I get $2 -e +1 + 1 + 4 + 0.5 = 8.5-e$ however the answer to the sum is different. The answer can be one of the following:
1) $10.5-e$ 2) $9.5 + e$ 3) $9-e$  4) $8.5 + 2e$

Comment: You dont need the absolute value in the logarithm because $x\ge 1$. All the other things seems ok.

Comment: I added some additional details to where my problem is, I thought that would be an issue with my immediate calculation of the antiderivative.

Comment: your calculation  is true.

Comment: Do you mean the end sum?

Comment: Thanks, I added the possible answers that I need to choose from. I'm really confused because none of the answers that can be correct don't include mine.

Comment: Yeah it's correct

Comment: I just found out that there was a correction to the exercise and $F(e)=\frac{5}{3}$. Sorry! In this case $10.5 - e$ is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that the function
$$
G(x)=\int_{1}^x f(t)\,dt
$$
is an antiderivative of $f$ on the interval $(0,\infty)$. Then, if $0<x1$,
$$
G(x)=\int_{1}^x\frac{1}{t^2}\,dt=\left[-\frac{1}{t}\right]_1^x
=1-\frac{1}{x}
$$
and, if $x>1$,
$$
G(x)=\int_{1}^x\frac{1}{t}\,dt=\Bigl[\ln t\Bigr]_1^x=\ln x
$$
so our function is
$$
G(x)=\begin{cases}
1-\dfrac{1}{x} & \text{if $0<x<1$}\\[4px]
0 & \text{if $x=0$}\\[4px]
\ln x & \text{if $x>1$}
\end{cases}
$$
All other antiderivatives differ from this one by a constant. So you need to find $c$ so that $F(x)=G(x)+c$ has $F(e)=1$; then
$$
F(e)=G(e)+c=\ln e+c=1+c
$$
and $c=0$.

If you want $F(e)=\frac{5}{3}$, then
$$
\frac{5}{3}=G(e)+c=1+c
$$
and $c=\frac{2}{3}$.

For this last one,
$$
F(e^2)+F(e^{-1})+F(e)+F'(1/2)+F'(2)=
2+\frac{2}{3}+(1-e)+\frac{2}{3}+1+\frac{2}{3}+4+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{21}{2}-e
$$